# Apache Arrow C++ get data: table->column(0)->GetScalar(0).ValueOrDie()->Value<int32_t>() doesn't compile

Tags: c++

How can I get a value for a GetScalar on a table?.   This code used to work  a couple of years ago  but now something has changed.  Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong? Please see code below:

```
#include <arrow/api.h>

int main() {
  // create an Arrow array of int32_t values
  std::vector<int32_t> values = {1, 2, 3};
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> array;
  arrow::Int32Builder builder;
  builder.AppendValues(values);
  builder.Finish(&array);

  // create an Arrow table with a single column of int32_t values
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field> field = arrow::field("col", arrow::int32());
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>> fields = {field};
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Schema> schema = arrow::schema(fields);
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>> columns = {array};
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = arrow::Table::Make(schema, columns);

  // get the scalar value of the first element in the column
  int32_t value = table->column(0)->GetScalar(0).ValueOrDie()->Value<int32_t>();
  std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```